# javascript var with right caret gives odd results

Tags: javascript, html, var

When I run this code:

```
var newHtml = "<jsp:include page=m_searchform.jsp> ";
```

My page won't load and I get errors.

When I run this code:

```
var newHtml = "<>jsp:include page=m_searchform.jsp ";
```

It loads up fine. Why would the right caret at the end of the string give me problems like this?

What I really want to do is put this into the innerHTML of some div:

```
<div id = "searchWrapper">
<form style="vertical-align:50%;" name = "searchForm" action="m_search.jsp">
<input class="searchBox" type="search" name="w"/>
<input class = "greenBtn" type="submit" value="Search"/></form>
</div>
```

But that's not working either. I put backslashes before all my quotation marks, but I'm sure I'm missing five other things and three huge concepts.

Comment: Doesn't JSP provide some sort of facility for HTML-encoding text/output?

Comment: Assigning the var works fine for me, at least in the Chrome console...http://cl.ly/image/0f3X1f0q1Y2A What are the errors? What is the rest of the code?

Comment: He says it doesnt show up because it doesnt, its not a valid HTML tag so it doesnt even get drawn. He would have to extract the wrapper code that would be generated by that jsp include and use that html in his js variable assignment.

Comment: I mean that it's throwing some type of error and none of my page shows up. When I try to assign the var = "<> blah blah blah" there is no error and my web page is all there.

Answer (score 2):

Try using &lt; and &gt; if you want the chars to show up

Edit #2:

As per epascarello's answer (and comments), my edit #2 will not be enough by its self. You will either need to pull all linebreaks out of that JSP include file, or you will need to use a search and replace function to replace line breaks on the imported text before printing it out, all on the JSP side of things.

I figured it out - lol, you can use your JSP tags in the javascript like you are doing but, The reason why your page wont load and you get errors is bcause your server is parsing that JSP tag (when you have it correctly written), and is thus injecting the html. I suppose this could work, however you would have to wrap your JSP tags in a single quote rather than double quotes since the HTML the server is going to inject there is going to have a bunch of double quotes inside of it!

So just do this:

```
var newHtml = '<jsp:include page=m_searchform.jsp>';
```

Edit #1:

You have do something like this, because you cannot insert JSP tags from javascript. The server is done parsing JSP before JS execution begins.

```
var newhtml = '<div id = "searchWrapper">
<form style="vertical-align:50%;" name = "searchForm" action="m_search.jsp">
<input class="searchBox" type="search" name="w"/>
<input class = "greenBtn" type="submit" value="Search"/></form>
</div>';


someObject.innerHTML = newhtml;
```

Comment: And i'm not positive but I think JSP tags are server side, so you wont be able to load them in via javascript, the server wont be parsing anymore at that point... I could be wrong though, I've never used JSP, though I think its like PHP in that its server parsed.

Comment: That may be a potential problem for me then.

Comment: you forgot the seimicolons? (;)

Comment: please be aware of the single quote container around that HTML, since you're using lots of double quotes its easier to wrap in single quotes than have to escape all your double quotes.

Comment: edit #1 works great for what I want to do. I tried double quotes instead of single and that worked too. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1):

So when you do this, you are expecting the server to add HTML content into a JavaScript variable.

```
var newHtml = "<jsp:include page=m_searchform.jsp> ";
```

when you view the page source it will look something like this

```
var newHtml = "<input type="text" name="asdasdas" />
<input type="text" name="sdfsdf" />
<input type="text" name="werwe" />";
```

And that is not valid JavaScript

Comment: This is exactly correct and why he should wrap in single quotes instead of double quotes!

Comment: Actually single quotes will not help since there would be new lines in it and those new lines would cause an error.

Comment: ah yeah. Doh! he would have to use the jsp equivalent of preg_replace and remove the line breaks...

Answer (score 0):

you should escape html characters such as `<>&()` before putting them into a HTML document.

```
string.split("&").join("&amp;").split("<").join("&lt;").split(">").join("&gt;").split("(").join("&#40;").split(")").join("&#41;")
```

should do the trick

Comment: You missed it just like i did at first... hes trying to inject JSP code to be parsed and thats not happening because hes not server side anymore at the point of js execution.

Comment: oh, right.  JS is client-side, JSP is server-side.  Injecting this would just put the string into the page; it wouldn't be parsed.  If Chase wants to call a JSP, this IS NOT the way to go.